# Unbox value from Either<L, R> vavr

Tags: java, functional-programming, monads, either, vavr

### Background

I have a small function that can return `Either<String, Float>`. If it succeed it returns a float otherwise an error string.

My objective is to perform a series of operations in a pipeline, and to achieve railway oriented programming using Either.

### Code

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import io.vavr.control.Either;

@Test
public void run(){

    Function<Float, Either<String, Float>> either_double = num -> {
        if(num == 4.0f)
            Either.left("I don't like this number");
        return Either.right(num * 2);
    };

    Function<Float, Float> incr = x -> x + 1.0f;

    Float actual = 
       Either.right(2f)
        .map(incr)
        .map(either_double)
        .get();

    Float expected = 6.0f;

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

This code does a series of simple operations. First I create a either of right with value 2, then I increment it and I finish by doubling it. The result of these operations is 6.

### Problem

The result of the mathematical operations is 6.0f, but that's not what I get. Instead I get `Right(6.0f)`.

This is an issue that prevents the code from compiling. I have a value *boxed* inside the Either Monad, but after checking their [API for Either](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Either.html) I didn't find a way to unbox it and get the value *as is*.

I thought about using `getOrElseGet` but even that method returns a Right.

### Question

How do I access the real value stored inside the Either Monad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flatMap(either_double)` instead of `map(either_double)`.

Comment: I still get an error: "The method flatmap(Function<Float,Either<String,Float>>) is undefined for the type Either<Object,Float>"

Comment: Give explicit type to `Either.right(2f)` ( `Either.<String, Float>right(2f)`)

Comment: Results in yet another error: "The method flatmap(Function<Float,Either<String,Float>>) is undefined for the type Either<String,Float>"  . Am I missing some operation to bridge both map and flatmap?

Comment: **M** is capital in `flatMap`

Comment: Ahh, I am officially an idiot. Well checked ! Could you add the explicit type to your answer? I am still going to accept it regardless, but it would future readers.

Comment: If it finally compiles you can try to remove explicit type from `right`, now it may be able to guess it correctly.